# Using fragment for Google map in xml showing error of "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class fragment"

Tags: android, android-fragments, dictionary

I am working on a project in which I need to show a Map in home screen. I used fragment class.
When I first lunch my screen, it is showing map successfully. But when I again click on Home or again come back from another screen to that map screen, below error is showing and app crashes.

```
"android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class fragment"
```

Here is my xml class.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >   

    <fragment        
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/homemap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"       
        map:cameraTilt="50"
        map:cameraZoom="40" />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And below is my Java class**

```
public class Customer_Home_Map extends Fragment {

public Customer_Home_Map() {
}

private GoogleMap theMap;
ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
ArrayList<SafetyResults_SearchResult> lstresult;
double lati = 0.0, longi = 0.0; 
GPSTracker gps;
GoogleMap mMap;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
int locationCount = 0;
API api = API.getInstance();
private HashMap<Marker, MyMarker> mMarkersHashMap;
private ArrayList<MyMarker> mMyMarkersArray = new ArrayList<MyMarker>();    

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_home_map,
    // container,
    // false);

     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_home_map,
            null);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
            up.getFont_Lato_Regular());

    gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());

    showAddress();  


    return view;
}

private void showAddress() {
     if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        lati = gps.getLatitude();
        longi = gps.getLongitude();

        straddress = getMyLocationAddress(lati, longi);
    }


    mMarkersHashMap = new HashMap<Marker, MyMarker>();

    setUpMap();

    plotMarkers(mMyMarkersArray);

}


private void plotMarkers(ArrayList<MyMarker> markers) {
    if (markers.size() > 0) {
        for (MyMarker myMarker : markers) {

            // Create user marker with custom icon and other options
            MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker
                            .getmLongitude()));

            markerOption.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.marker));

            Marker currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);
            mMarkersHashMap.put(currentMarker, myMarker);

            mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
    // map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.homemap)).getMap();

        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lati, longi);
        CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                coordinate, 15);

        mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);

        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.

        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(
                        com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker) {
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } else
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Unable to create Maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


public class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    public MarkerInfoWindowAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);

        MyMarker myMarker = mMarkersHashMap.get(marker);

        ImageView markerIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_icon);

        TextView markerLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_label);

        markerIcon.setImageResource(manageMarkerIcon(myMarker.getmIcon()));

        markerLabel.setText(myMarker.getmLabel());

        TextView anotherLabel = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.another_label);
        // anotherLabel.setText("A custom text");

        return v;
    }
}

private int manageMarkerIcon(String markerIcon) {
    if (markerIcon.equalsIgnoreCase("3"))
        return R.drawable.ambulance;
    else if (markerIcon.equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
        return R.drawable.doctor;
    else if (markerIcon.equalsIgnoreCase("me"))
        return R.drawable.marker;
    else
        return R.drawable.marker;
}
```

}

**I am attaching my logcat error snap below**

[image]

Comment: Remove `MapFragment` from `FragmentTrasaction onDestryoView(...)`  in `Fragment`. There is only one workaround till now.

Comment: remove this from the xml code of fragment     xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: Please give me code , where I need to remove it and how ?

Comment: I also removed MapFragment @Override
 public void onDestroyView() {
  super.onDestroyView();
  MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
    R.id.homemap);
  if (f != null)
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
 }    It help me when I come back from another screen to this screen, but when i call same screen by selecting from side menu bar, app crashes. Please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

this is xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".Googlemap.Googlemap">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and code should be something like this

```
  private GoogleMap googleMap;
 if (googleMap == null) {



            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

hopefully this will work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. But if you will see my code, I have done same task.  My issue is not about showing Map. Map is showing when I lunch first time but when user come back from another screen to this screen, app crashes. I hope you got my issue. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot and now I found solutions of my problem.

I write below code in my activity.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    try {
        MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.homemap);

        if (getActivity().isFinishing()) {              
        }

        else if (f != null)
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f)
                    .commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Thanks All for giving you valuable time and suggestions.